# In a non-inertial reference frame can an object have zero inertia?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, momentum, mass, inertia

Can an object in a non-inertial reference frame have zero or NO inertia?

Comment: What do you mean by "have zero inertia"?

Comment: No inertia is what I mean.

Comment: what do you mean by no inertia? You mean zero mass as some of the answers suggested?

Answer (score 1):

If you did an experiment to find the inertia of a large massive object, for example by accelerating it by $2ms^{-2}$ to the right, and your non inertial frame accelerated at $2ms^{-2}$ to the left - then you would find that you've achieved the acceleration of the object with no force.

So for that particular example the object seemed to have no inertia.

The problem is that inertia is usually regarded as a scalar quantity of the object, measured in kg.  If you wanted to accelerate the same object by $2ms^{-2}$ to the left (as viewed from your accelerating frame) it would need twice as much force as would be needed in an inertial frame.

So the conclusion is no, an object cannot have zero inertia in a non-inertial frame, unless the frame were continuously changed depending on the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. If what you mean by inertia is resistance to forces (and thus mass), the system will have mass no matter in which reference frame you are. There is no way to change the mass of a system to zero, unless you are talking about light, but that is a completely different thing and there is no physical reference frame adapted to light-like motion.

Answer (score 0):

If inertia is the resistance to changing velocity, ie the same as inertial mass, then no. If an object had no inertial mass it could accelerate in any direction with no force applied. Tapping a heavy-looking object could give it an enormous velocity.

In a non-inertial frame we see things accelerating when we can see no application of force, but these accelerations are in specific directions and we invent fictitious forces to explain these movements.